# Web API: DelegatingHandler using CancellationToken

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cancellation-token

The typical Web API DelegatingHandler implementation looks like this...

```
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // TODO: Do work before inner handler here

    // Call the inner handler.
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    // TODO: Do work _after_ inner handler here

    return response;
}
```

What is the preferred method for dealing with **CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == true**?

Should I:

- Generate an error response and break the delegate chain?
- Do nothing (as above)?
- Option 'C'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Cancellation semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) are to throw an exception when the token is cancelled (e.g., `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`).

If you don't have any asynchronous work to do (other than `base.SendAsync`), then you can just ignore the token.

Note that `await base.SendAsync` may raise an exception if the token is cancelled. The exception will propagate naturally, but if you have any cleanup that must take place regardless of cancellation, use a `using` or `finally` block.

Comment: From the link above...The implementer of a cancelable operation determines, in the user delegate, how to terminate the operation in response to a cancellation request. In many cases, the user delegate can just perform any required cleanup and then return immediately....so I guess there aren't any real "requirements" just "best effort".  Thanks for the info.